# Illustrator Javascript: Select Based on Swatch

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

Is there anyway to make a Javascript Illustrator script that will select everything in the document that has a particular color? I can't find any information anywhere. I do know that you can do what I'm asking with the Select drop down menu, but I need this as part of a script.

I've tried something like:

`myDoc.selection = Spot.name("CutContour");`

and

`myDoc.selection = myDoc.spots.item("CutContour");`

but neither work.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you. The fillColor attribute of an object is not a reference to the swatch object ( so we could check its name ). Its the description of the color itself (no strings attached to the swatch panel). Once that said, we need to look for teh color typename and its values to have a match. However if you specify CutContour and two colours have this name, it's possible teh result aren't the one expected.

```
function getObjectsByColor ( colorName )
{
var doc, items, i = 0, n = 0, item, color, selectionArray = [];

if ( app.documents.length == 0 ){ 
    alert("No documents open");
    return;
}

doc = app.activeDocument;
try
{
    color = doc.swatches.getByName ( colorName );
}
catch(e)
{
    alert( "No such color !");
    return;
}

color = color.color ;

items = doc.pageItems;
n = items.length;
if ( items.length == 0 )
{
    alert( "No items found");
    return;
}

for ( i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
{
    item = items[i];
    if ( item.fillColor.typename == color.typename
    && item.fillColor.cyan == color.cyan
    && item.fillColor.magenta == color.magenta
    && item.fillColor.yellow == color.yellow
    && item.fillColor.black == color.black )
    {
        selectionArray [ selectionArray.length ] = item;
    }
}

if ( selectionArray.length == 0 )
{
    alert( "Nothing found" );
    return;
}

app.selection = selectionArray;
}

getObjectsByColor ("CutContour");
```

Loic

PS: Are you using a Caldera RIP ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way for this. This script to the same operation as "Select Same Fill Color" do in Illustrator. Commented code as well for your help. It works perfectly in Illustrator CC 2017

```
app.selection = null;
if (app.activeDocument.length > 0) {
    try {
        var swatch = app.activeDocument.swatches.getByName('CMYK Red');
        var temp = app.documents[0].pathItems.rectangle(10, 10, 150, 150);
        temp.fillColor = swatch.color;

        // To select object that have CMYK Red swatch applied to stroke and fill.
        app.executeMenuCommand('Find Fill & Stroke menu item');

        // To select object that have CMYK Red swatch applied to fill.
        app.executeMenuCommand('Find Fill Color menu item');

        // To select object that have CMYK Red swatch applied to stroke.
        app.executeMenuCommand('Find Stroke Color menu item');

        temp.remove();
    } catch (e) {
        alert('CMYK Red swatch does not exists!!')
    }
}
```